# moto mock_ses list_identities(IdentityType='EmailAddress') returns both email addresses and domains

Tags: python, pytest, boto3, amazon-ses, moto

I'm using `mock_ses` from `moto` to mock aws ses functions. I want to test some functions that uses `list_identities()` but the mocked `list_identities()` does not behave the same way as the actual function, and I cannot figure out why.

The actual `list_identities()` function can take `IdentityType` argument to only return list of email addresses or list of domains as defined [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses/client/list_identities.html). But it looks like the mocked `list_identities()` function always returns a list that includes both email addresses and domains event if the `IdentityType` is set.

I have created a simplified unit test to demonstrate my issue. I would expect this unit test to pass, but it fails because the value of `mock_response` is `['testdomain.com', 'user1@testdomain.com', 'user2@testdomain.com']`.  it's including the `testdomain.com` in the list when I only want to get the list of email addresses.

I'm using `moto 4.2.6`

```
from moto import mock_ses

@mock_ses
class Test_TestEmailSenderTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    # Setup actions for each test
    def setUp(self):
        ses_client = boto3.client("ses", "us-west-2")
        self.ses_client = ses_client
        ses_client.verify_email_identity(EmailAddress="user1@testdomain.com")
        ses_client.verify_email_identity(EmailAddress="user2@testdomain.com")
        ses_client.verify_domain_dkim(Domain='testdomain.com')
        
    # Teardown actions for each test
    def tearDown(self):
        ses_client = boto3.client("ses", "us-west-2")
        try:
            ses_client.delete_identity(Identity="user1@testdomain.com")
            ses_client.delete_identity(Identity="user2@testdomain.com")
            ses_client.delete_identity(Identity="testdomain.com")
        except:
            pass
        

    def test_get_email_address(self):
        expected_response = ["user1@testdomain.com","user2@testdomain.com"]
        mock_response = self.ses_client.list_identities(IdentityType='EmailAddress')["Identities"]
        self.assertEqual(mock_response, expected_response)
```

Comment: That argument is not supported yet by Moto, but if you open an issue with them, they can probably implement it fairly quickly. https://github.com/getmoto/moto/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IdentityType`-argument is supported as of [Moto 4.2.7](https://pypi.org/project/moto/4.2.7/), just released.

See the ChangeLog: https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Yes I see the changes, thanks!